# Fetching Jobless Claims from the US department of labour (dol)

Tags: xml, database, http, web, get

I have signed up for a developer account with the (US) department of labour. I am trying to fetch the initial jobless claims data and when using:

http://api.dol.gov/V1/Statistics/OUI_InitialClaims/unemploymentInsuranceInitialClaims?KEY=

it works fine except for it shows data from the 60s (i'm assuming the time series is reversed) When I try to skip using the function ?$skip=5 added as such:

http://api.dol.gov/V1/Statistics/OUI_InitialClaims/unemploymentInsuranceInitialClaims?KEY=?$skip=5

the api returns xml reading unauthorized 401 (i couldn't post the xml because of the tags :c)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @FreepromTech. If you found an answer to your
question, please consider [accepting
it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) (by clicking the
check-mark), and consider up-voting it (by clicking the up arrow).
Accepting an answer indicates to the wider community that you've
found a solution, gives yourself some reputation points, and gives
some reputation points to the person who answered your question.
If you did not find a satisfactory answer to your question, please
leave a comment.

Comment: I haven't found an answer

Comment: You haven't explained why your syntax error is not the answer: "You cannot have two question marks in a URL."

Comment: i know, stack exchange made me leave a comment in order to keep this thread open

Comment: I don't understand. Why is the answer not acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Those URLs will give 401 errors to everyone who tries them, unless they also have a developer account with the DOL. That doesn't seem highly likely.

In any case, one thing jumps out at me right away. Your second URL has a syntax error. Notice that StackOverflow's syntax highlighting doesn't like it either. A URL contains only one question mark. See the entry for [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) on Wikipedia for how to construct a valid URL containing a query string.

Comment: I have a developer account, as i mentioned in the post, i simply removed the key (for obvious reasons). It is the second URL in specific that doesn't work. The DOL api suggested using a ?$skip= for the paramaters ( see http://developer.dol.gov/accessing-the-apis-using-http-requests/ )

Comment: Did you even read my second paragraph or click on the link I provided? You cannot have two question marks in a URL.